# Как получить group и id кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.6, kivy

Через цикл создается не важно какое количество Toggle Button, как просто по нажатию на любую из них вывести в print её параметры id и group?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton, ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        gl=GridLayout(rows=20, cols=0)
        i=0
        while i < 20:
            gl.add_widget(ToggleButton(text='Кнопка '+str(i), id=str(i), group=(i), on_press=self.pressed_btn))
            i+=1
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(gl)
        runTouchApp(root)
    def pressed_btn(self):
        print('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 1))
        gl = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        gl.bind(minimum_height=gl.setter("height"))

        for i in range(20):
            gl.add_widget(
                ToggleButton(
                    text=f'Кнопка {i}',
                    group=i,
                    on_press=self.pressed_btn,
                    size_hint_y=None,
                    height=36,
                )
            )

        root.add_widget(gl)
        return root

    def pressed_btn(self, instance_toggle_button):
        print(instance_toggle_button, instance_toggle_button.group)


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Не подскажете, что если добавлять в gl еще label'ы
self.lbl=Label(text='текст', id=i)
self.gl.add_widget(self.lbl)
Как менять, например, Label с id=1 по нажатию кнопки?
Пытался так: self.lbl.ids['1'].text='новый текст' и по-разному

Comment: Устанавливать id для объекта в Python коде бессмысленно. Потому что id == instance.

Comment: group тоже бессмысленно использовать?

Comment: Нет, не бессмысленно.